# I want to out 112233..increase number,how can I do?

Tags: c#

```
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){Response.Write(i);}
```

### //out 12345

how to change regular to out 1122334455 .. how can I do?

Comment: you could use `Response.Write(i);` twice in the loop body to print each number twice.

Comment: Or use `$"{i}{i}"` - look up string interpolation

Comment: In your question you say you want to output the value `1122333` (notice the three 3's you listed). Was that a typo or, do actually want to display each digit as a multiplier of the index?

Comment: @logic30 Can you explain in details what are you trying to achieve and which conditions to follow?

Answer (score 2):

> *"I want to output* `1122334455`*"*

You can just output the value of `i` twice in the loop instead of once:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++) 
{
    Response.Write($"{i}{i}");
}
```

Comment: I want change regular to out 112233...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. This code will output `1122334455`

Comment: sorry,I do not explain very clear,I just need  one variable,like i or j or i++...etc.thanks!

Comment: Still not clear what you mean = there is only one variable - `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply
`for(int i = 11; i <= 55; i += 11){Response.Write(i);}`